# Team Explorer Everywhere with Eclipse authentication

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm using Team Explorer Everywhere with Eclipse. When I try to check-in my changes I get the following error:

> Access denied connecting to TFS server myServerAddress (authenticating as myComputerName/myUser)

I tried to use CrossPlatformCommandLine tool with the `tf profile` command, but i got the following message

> An argument error occurred: The command 'profile' is unknown

How can I manage my credentials?

Comment: Are you using TEE 2010 or 2012?  Are you on Windows?  Mac OS?  Some other platform?

Comment: @sinisha what is "Team Explorer"....can u please give me a brief...actually i m new in android and "tees maar khan" hm log expert ko bolte hai ...so dont mind that..ok

Comment: @Goldie Team Foundation Server (commonly abbreviated to TFS) is a Microsoft product offering source control, data collection, reporting, and project tracking, and is intended for collaborative software development projects. TEE is a java-based plugin to the Eclipse IDE that allows team members to access TFS

Answer (score 8):

Profiles were removed from Team Explorer Everywhere 2012.  The authentication in TEE 2012 is as follows:

1. If you have specified credentials on the command-line, those will be used.
2. If you have specified credentials for your TFS server, those will be used.

   - On Windows, TEE will use credentials in the [Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/What-is-Credential-Manager).
   - On Mac OS, TEE will use credentials in Keychain.
   - On other Unix systems, TEE will use the file `$HOME/.microsoft/Team Foundation/4.0/Configuration/TEE-Servers/Credentials.xml`.
3. If no stored passwords are available, TEE 2012 will then try to authenticate with your currently logged-in user credentials.

   - On Windows, you will get single sign-on and not need to present a password if you are on the same domain as the TFS server, have a trust relationship between your logged-in domain and the TFS server's domain, or if you're using a "shadow account" on your local machine with a corresponding account on the TFS server.
   - On Unix platforms, if you have a Kerberos ticket, we will try to use that to authenticate (if the TFS server is configured to support Negotiate authentication.)
4. If you TEE cannot determine your logged-in user credentials, you will be prompted for your username and password, unless you have specified the `-noprompt` command-line option.

So, if Team Explorer Everywhere is not able to authenticate using your logged-in credentials, you can override this behavior by adding your credentials to the [Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/What-is-Credential-Manager).

Comment: When I tried adding credentials in CredentialManager I got the following error `Windows cannot save this information`. But I found a solution which works. When I want to check in something I first use `Disconect Project permanently` option, connect to server again and then I am able to check in

Comment: I would follow up with Microsoft Support as to why you get that error...  We really didn't intend for you to use "Disconnect Project Permanently" to, well, temporarily disconnect projects.  Reconnecting may not work well in a plurality of scenarios.

Comment: I asked this question on official Microsoft forum but I didn't get satisfying answer. And everything works fine on my Virtual Ubuntu machine on same computer( the problem is on my win 7 )

Comment: Adding a windows credential for my tfs server fixed it for me so it wasn't default logging as my current session. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Few days ago I downloaded updates for TEE and know everything works fine. I haven't made any other changes. Maybe it was some problem with previous version.

Comment: ya may be it was problem in previous version...hmmmmm